# add criteria to GET request in Rest api with VBA for Parse.com

Tags: vba, api, parse-platform

I looking for how to add criteria to a GET request to Parse.com in VBA.
In the code below i have used the criteria in the target URL and in the request header each by it self and ad you see it here.
What is get back is my entire Roll Call table.

```
Sub parseGetData(data As String)
    Text6 = ""

    Dim response As String
    TargetURL = "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/RollCall?'where':{'jDate':'09-29-2015'})"
    Set HTTPReq = createObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    HTTPReq.Open "GET", TargetURL, False
    HTTPReq.SetRequestHeader "X-Parse-Application-Id", AppID
    HTTPReq.SetRequestHeader "X-Parse-REST-API-Key", RestID
    HTTPReq.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    HTTPReq.SetRequestHeader "urlencode", "('where':{'jDate':'09-29-2015'})"
    HTTPReq.Send
    response = HTTPReq.ResponseText
    Text6 = response
End Sub
```